# Youtube, facebook video does not play on firefox

Tags: 16.04, firefox, video

I have installed ubuntun 16.04 and adobe flash player. I have also enabled html5 in youtube. Still I get following messages for lots of youtube videos. Some of videos play but lots of doesn't. I also have problem to play facebook videos. None of the facebook videos play on firefox. Am I missing some settings? Whats the solution for this?

[image]

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: latest version 58